# Have os.walk follow symlinks conditionally

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm using **Python 2.7**

I have a scenario like this

```
 for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(dir_tree, topdown=True, followlinks=True):
        for atom in files:
            # do something with files
        for dir in dirs:
            # do something with dirs
```

I am performing an `os.walk` on a directory tree. This tree has some links. some of these links point to other locations inside the directory tree. Some of the links do not. ***I want os.walk to only follow links that point to other location in the directory tree***

eg:

```
A/
   temp/
       collateral_file_1
   B/
       link1    ->   Somewhere outside A
       link2    ->   A/temp/
   C/
       file_1
```

In the above case `dir_tree` would A/ . When performing an `os.walk` on A I would like to explore `link2` as it is a link to another location within A. but not `link1`.

You might wonder why? The contents of `link1` would be explore in a non symlink following walk anyway. But the reason for this I am checking some file patterns that are fed in via a config file for certain properties.

eg: All files in `A/B/link1/` should have `700` permissions etc.

Is there a way I could do this?

I thought about `os.listdir` but it seems like there should be an easier way